# Cometd in wildfly8.1.0 no response

Tags: wildfly, cometd, wildfly-8

I'm trying to deploy a project which utilizes Cometd2.9.1 in Wildfly8.1.0.
The project worked in glassfish4.0, however it won't work in wildfly. It can be deployed with no problem, but it stuck after I visit `http://localhost:8080/Cometd3/` (Yes, the project name is Cometd3 while I ended up with cometd2.9.1)

It's weird because there is no error or exception message even I enabled debug log.
Because my log is too long to post here and I have completely no idea what is the problem, please download my log file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5ye4CP3K_a3emhSUTdDcFJZbDQ/edit?usp=sharing).

Please note that the log is just stop at

```
2014-09-17 14:57:09,893 FINE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-4) servletPath /faces
2014-09-17 14:57:09,900 FINE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-5) servletPath /faces
2014-09-17 14:57:09,907 FINE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-6) servletPath /faces
2014-09-17 14:58:44,505 DEBUG [org.jboss.ejb.client.txn] (Periodic Recovery) Send recover request for transaction origin node identifier 1 to EJB receiver with node name 972909-a43sv
```

And there are no other log after those messages.
What's more,when I say it is stuck, I mean not only the server side stuck, but also the browser, which means the browser is totally white and keep loading page when I open it.
Any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can answer only from the CometD side of things.

The logs shows some server-side CometD activity (a `LocalSession` called `echo` handshakes), but after that it's like there are no requests to the server, so that CometD has nothing to do and just sits idle.

From your description of the problem looks more like a server problem than a CometD problem.

CometD typically runs very well in Jetty; I would try to deploy your application in Jetty and see how it goes.

Comment: Thank you @sbordet, here is my application:https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5ye4CP3K_a3NUdqdHd0cFgwUWM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: BTW, it's a netbeans project zipped by winrar.

Comment: @nosnhoj Did you deploy it in Jetty ?

Comment: I don't know how to deploy it in Jetty, it shows `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet` while I deploy war.